# Unable to boot device because it cannot be located on disk., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The device's data is no longer present

Tags: swiftui, preview, swiftui-previews

GenericHumanReadableError: unexpected error occurred

Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot device because it cannot be located on disk., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The device's data is no longer present at /Users/lmenezes/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator Devices/95005A74-6203-46DE-8F70-779B3E96178E/data., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Use the device manager in Xcode or the simctl command line tool to either delete the device properly or erase contents and settings.}

I don't know how to solve this. This happened after I removed some data to clean space on my mac.
How do I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as you too, I removed some data to clean space on my mac happend the problem ,I have solve it , run xcrun simctl erase all in Terminal

Comment: "erase all" sounds dangerous. What does it do?